Identifying a few components in a SOLUPEAK 5V power supply, bonus for short description on how its regulated!
I have a Chifi 5 V PS and while it's adjustable, nothing past 5.1 V.
Ultimately I'd like to see what kind of mods would allow even 5.3 V.
I am familiar with very basic electronics and looking at the board presents a few unknowns.

Looks like two wirewound chokes?


I'm guessing an opamp (below the wire-wound resistor)? What do you folks think the part# is?



Here are 2 general images just in case someone has been here before.


FYI, SOLUPEAK 25 VA DC 5 V Linear Power Supply, 25VA power, DC 5 V @3.5 A max

What does "chifi" mean?

@Hearth I realized it after you asked. These supplies are sold as cheap low noise supplies for Hi-Fi use. Likely portmanteau of cheap Hi-Fi.

That same power supply is sold under many names.

Yes, inductors/chokes, wirewound over ferrite rod.

Analog Devices OP1776. From a photo of innards of another identical-looking power supply.


That supply has been discussed here before. Not sure if reverse-engineered schematics are available. There's not that many ways of building a linear regulator from op-amp and power transistor.
